# how do I force a latex project to the height/width of Springer's LNCS style?

Tags: margins, paper-size, lncs

I have a little paper and for the submision it must have the [LNCS style](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0). The problem is that I added some figures and charts and somehow the width/height messed up, so any idea of how to force a document to the height/width of LNCS style?.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For example: `\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{MWE to demonstrate how to place to images side-by-side}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}` has figures, but doesn't have a width/height problem.

Comment: Generally, it is rather difficult to alter the width and height of the text block after `\begin{document}` and, certainly, of the paper size. So something in your code is doing something special/unusual/odd (delete as preferred).

Comment: Please see https://latextemplates.github.io/LNCS/ for a maintained version of an advanced ready-to-start LNCS template. Maybe that helps.